# Blog post URL redirects to a Page URL who's slug is a prefix of the post slug.

Tags: redirect, slug

I have a page with slug 'what', and a blog post with a slug which *begins* with 'what' (ie. 'what-is-this-blog-about'). For some reason when navigating directly to the blog post URL the user is redirected to the page. In other words the page slug is a *prefix* of the post url. Is this the normal behaviour? If so, how can I change it?

Comment: what is your permalink structure? that typically happens when the original request is a 404, and WordPress tries to guess what you've requested.

Comment: My link structure is '/weblog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%'. The post definitely exists, the redirect happens even when I navigate to the post from the edit page.

Comment: do you have the issue if you disable all plugins and use a default theme? that definitely isn't normal behaviour.